# MCP23017 - detecting state of IOCON.BANK bit after MCU reset

Tags: microchip

Datasheet for reference [here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001952C.pdf).

The port registers of the MCP23017 I2C I/O expander can be configured in two ways using the `IOCON.BANK` bit as follows:

> If BANK = 0, the A/B registers are paired. For
>   example, IODIRA is mapped to address 00h and
>   IODIRB is mapped to the next address (address
>   01h). The mapping for all registers is from 00h
>   -15h.
>
> If BANK = 1, the registers associated with each
>   port are segregated. Registers associated with
>   PORTA are mapped from address 00h - 0Ah and
>   registers associated with PORTB are mapped
>   from 10h - 1Ah.

By changing the `IOCON.BANK` bit, the address of the `IOCON` register itself changes, see table 3-4, 3-5 in the datasheet.

So, in the case of a MCU reset, how do you determine the state of `IOCON.BANK` *without* resetting the MCP23017 so that any peripherals attached to the MCP23017 are unaffected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My conclusion is that you cannot determine the state of IOCON.BANK, but you can however get it into a known value without resetting the MCP23017 using the following procedure:

1. Assume `IOCON.BANK = 1`
2. Read register 0x05.
3. Clear bit 7 (presumably the `BANK` bit) of the stored value then write that value back to 0x05.

At this point you have either:

- Switched from `BANK = 1` to `BANK = 0`

or

- Disabled `GPINTENB.GPINT7`

To finish, set `GPINTENB.GPINT7` if needed.

You now have a known state with `IOCON.BANK = 0`.

Comment: I was hoping the answer wasn't something like this, but I'm glad you've given me a clear solution.